# How can i work AJAX update JSON with Datatable (Datatable.JS) - Django?

Tags: python, json, django, datatable

I have tried to work ajax update from Django to Datatable templates like this code

template [shipment.html]

```
      <table id="example">
        <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>User</th>
           <th>Author</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
       </table>
```

i'm use this to got a json data and then now show this already.

views.py

```
def getlist(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = serializers.serialize("json", Editors.objects.all())
        respon = json.loads(data)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(respon, ensure_ascii=False),
                            content_type="application/json")
```

json (getlist)

```
[{"model": "tracking.editors", "pk": 1, "fields": {"editor_name": "This AA", "num_users": 10}}, {"model": "tracking.editors", "pk": 2, "fields": {"editor_name": "This BB", "num_users": 20}}, {"model": "tracking.editors", "pk": 3, "fields": {"editor_name": "This CC", "num_users": 30}}, {"model": "tracking.editors", "pk": 4, "fields": {"editor_name": "This DD", "num_users": 40}}]
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "{% url 'getlist' %}",
                type: 'GET',
                dataSrc: "",
            },
            columns: [
                {data: "fields.editor_name"},
                {data: "fields.num_users"},
            ],
        });



    });

</script>
```

Now it's data is already show on my Table but not Real-time update.
How can i do it's to Real-time update when have a new record in my Database?

i need someone to help for clear of this can be used like my method or need use by our method, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use Django, I recommend changing paths for your scenario. There is the HTMX js library which is fantastic for Django. It sends the request to the server and renders a response in html. You update your pages with partials without refreshing with clean and maintainable code.
This is the best way if you want to use Django for the front end and reduce some spaghetti code.If I went off topic, I apologize.